# closed-loop inverse kinematics

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ROS fans..

I have made a node that controls ax-12 servo motors by using inverse kinematics algorithm. The result is good.. but I want to improve the performance better. So I Have to use closed-loop inverse kinematics algorithm.. I never try it.. and I want to try it now..

Are there ROS packages which I can learn about closed-loop inverse kinematics ?

Thanks.. I hope someone can help me :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/61645/closed-loop-inverse-kinematics/) by [Rizqa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3771/rizqa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 45 on 2013-04-26

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cagatay](https://answers.ros.org/users/2526/cagatay/) on 2013-04-27**:
for closed-form inverse kinematics, you can use openrave's ikfast compiler. Openrave has wrapper for ROS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can try following [this](http://ros.org/wiki/Industrial/Tutorials/Create_a_Fast_IK_Solution) tutorial to generate an IKFast solution, as suggested by @cagatay.  You'll need to create a DAE file from your robot's URDF, and will need to install the openrave software.  But, after that, the steps are fairly straightforward.

Note that IKFast is pretty good, but is unable to find solutions for all robot geometries.  In particular, it only handles robots with 6 joints; additional joint beyond that must be specified as "free joints".  It can handle prismatic joints, but with a few limitations.

Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [Jeremy Zoss](https://answers.ros.org/users/3925/jeremy-zoss/) with karma: 4976 on 2013-04-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Rizqa](https://answers.ros.org/users/3771/rizqa/) on 2013-04-28**:
Thanks @Jeremy Zoss and @cagatay